# Install extension in Magento 2 in local server from zip

Tags: localhost, magento2

Actually I know how to install extension which are are available in the stores. But  my problem is how to install extension in Magento 2 which is installed locally and I have third party extension downloaded locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can install downloaded extension by just copying files from extension folder into app/code folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload your extension on server for example your extension name is `Mycompany_Custommenu` and you upload extension to `/var/www/html/extension/` folder path.
2. Run below command in terminal.

   ```
   composer config repositories.mycompany_custommenu path /var/www/html/extension/Custommenu/
   ```
3. Next run below command.

   ```
   composer require mycompany/custommenu
   ```
4. Run `setup:upgrade` to enable Module.